# ReportLab text overlapping

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I am completely new to reportlab pdf creation. I am trying to print a few lines and this is the output I get. How do I increase the gap between lines?

```
doc = SimpleDocTemplate("form.pdf", pagesize=(3.93*inch, 5.77*inch), rightMargin=10,leftMargin=10, topMargin=1.67*inch, bottomMargin=0.77*inch)
Story=[]

styles=getSampleStyleSheet()
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Center', alignment=TA_CENTER))
styles.wordWrap = 'LTR'

ptext = '<font size=18 face=Vera-Bold>We would like to welcome you We would like to welcome you</font>'
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `leading` parameter of `ParagraphStyle` to something larger.

Comment: Could you please share any link where I can get all the details about it? I could not find much in the docs.

Comment: The Reportlab docs aren't very good, but you can find it in the PDF manual. https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf

Comment: I have another question related to ReportLab... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59032495/static-position-of-text-and-qr Would you mind answering it? Sorry for asking like this... kind of on a deadline